# VBS pass MS Access DB Connection variable to HTA

Tags: vbscript, parameters, database-connection, connection-string, hta

I have an HTA(1) file that I call another HTA(2) file from. I would like to open a database connection in the first file and then reference it in the second file to save on redundant connections to the database.

I know how to pass string variables from HTA(1) to HTA(2), but I have been unable to Set the connection variable to the passed in string value. Here's some code.....

HTA(1):

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Chr(34) & "C:/Users/******/Desktop/Cycle Mapping Menu.HTA" & Chr(34) & " #" & objConn &"#"
```

I use the # to delimit. The objConn is the connection variable. The connection is valid and I can use it to talk to the database.

On the receiving side...

HTA(2):

```
<html>
<head>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="myhta" APPLICATIONNAME="FSTRUC Mapping Interface">
    <title>FSTRUC Mapping Interface</title>
    <script language="vbscript">

     a = Split(myhta.CommandLine, "#")
    msgbox myhta.commandline

    for x = 0 to 1
        if trim(a(x)) <> "" then
            msgbox x & " " & a(x)
        end if
    next

    Set objConn = a(1)
```

The code fails on the 'Set objConn = a(1)'

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Nope, only text can be passed as a command line so the closest you can get is to pass the connection string to avoid duplicating it.  You could always just make HTA1 do whatever HTA2 does.

Comment: Maybe I will end up using just HTA(1). I just don't want to recreate the connection as that takes time... Can I use the connection string to create the object?

Comment: Passing a connection string would still require you to open a new connection, you just would not need to have it in two places.

Comment: ok. I can't accept a comment as an answer.